# Python: Assigning multiple values to sublist without using .append()?

Tags: python, numpy

Is there any way to assign multiple values into sublists without using the .append()-function?
For example, I have the following list:

```
l = np.zeros((5,1))
```

which gives:

```
array([[0.],
   [0.],
   [0.],
   [0.],
   [0.]])
```

Is there a possibility of inserting multiple values into l, such as l[0] = (2,1), to obtain:

```
array([[2.,1.],
   [0.],
   [0.],
   [0.],
   [0.]])
```

Additionally, is there any way to extend the list l for continuously writing new values into l[0], without using .extend() (for example when looping through elements in a different list)?

**Edit:**
For example:

```
list2 = random.sample(range(10, 100), 500)
for i in list2:
   if list2[i] < 50:
       l[0].extend(element):
```

How can I write all numbers <50 into my sublist `l[0]` without using the .extend()-function?

Comment: I'm afraid your example is still not clear. Are you using numpy or not? Also, `l` is a single-level list. Accessing `l[0]` returns an `int`, what do you expect `l[0].extend` to do? you should provide an expected output

Comment: You can make an object array and put a list or another numpy array inside it, but it is currently still very unclear what you are trying to do.

Comment: object array example: `l = np.full((5,1), 0., dtype=np.object)` and then `l[0][0] = np.array([2,1], dtype=np.float)`

Comment: Don't confuse `list` and `numpy` array.  `l` is not a list of lists.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using numpy, you have to play by its rules.

```
l = np.zeros((5, 1))
l[0] = [2, 1]
```

Will fail with error

```
ValueError: cannot copy sequence with size 2 to array axis with dimension 1
```

If you create a 2D array, then it will work.

```
l = np.zeros((5, 2))
l[0] = [2, 1]
print(l)
```

outputs

```
[[2. 1.]
 [0. 0.]
 [0. 0.]
 [0. 0.]
 [0. 0.]]
```

Comment: But what do you do if you don't know how many elements you will add to a sublist? If I have a while-loop throgh a big list, and add elements if they satisfy a certain condition..

Comment: @paulsen001 I'm not sure what you mean. Edit the **question** with [mcve]